# Resolution compatible - HTML

Tags: html, css

I have this problem with my navigation menu in which when I change my screen resolution, the menu gets all messed up. This is my code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qh5u47t2/. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<div id="topMenuDiv" style="background-color: gray; height: 20%; width:99%; margin: 0 0 -2px 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; border: 1px solid red;">
    <div class="navigation" style="height:100%; width:100%;">
        <ul class="menu">
```

These are the main HTML codes for my menu and the CSS is:

```
.navigation {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.menu {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    left: 20%;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: You have 2 solutions, learn `media-queries` or just use a framework like `Bootstrap` it will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried re-sizing your JSfiddle, and it seems to me that your code is not responsive in a way that if not enough 'space' is allocated on the top window (viewable area), it will not reflow the content to show it all.
The Bootstrap Grid system will assist you getting the work done, including dealing with various screen resolutions right out of the box.
In my experience it is well worth learning.
A few links to get you started: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid (The Grid System)
You can see some templates here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

Hope it helps